# Is there a way to make lxml preserve &nbsp like beautifulSoup?

Tags: python, lxml

I use lxml to parse html files, make some changes and convert html doc to string. however I found that it change the "&nbsp;" to " ".

here is my sample code:

```
from lxml import html

h = "<p>&nbsp;hello&nbsp;</p>"
p = html.fromstring(h, parser=html.HTMLParser(encoding='utf-8'))
print html.tostring(p, pretty_print=True, encoding='utf-8')
```

and here is the output:

```
<p> hello </p>
```